# How can I split a txt file with encoding as delimiter in python or R?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text-processing

'þ' and 'ÿ' are the delimiters

```
1þ2þ3þ4þ5þ6ÿ7

1þ2þ3þ4þ5þ6ÿ7
```

The output data frame should be as following

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I tried reading using pandas with the following but it did not work

```
df= pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/File.txt',encoding ='iso-8859-1',sep='[þ,ÿ]', engine ="python",header=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
df= pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/File.txt', sep='[þ,ÿ]', engine ="python",header=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can try this :

```
my_cols = [str(i) for i in range(7)]
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='þ|ÿ', engine='python', names=my_cols, header=None)
print(df)

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```